# Can an open-source Node.js project (MEAN stack) be licensed under the GPLv3?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, licensing

I want to start a simple open-source software project as a way to learn the MEAN stack, and I'm wondering if I can release the code on Github under the GPLv3.

- MongoDB (AGPL v3)
- Express.js (MIT)
- AngularJS (MIT)
- Node.js (MIT)

Also Bootstrap 3 (Apache 2.0 or MIT?) and maybe jQuery (MIT). There's also the question of whatever gets installed into node_modules.

Can a project like this be licensed under the GPLv3? The MIT License, Apache 2.0 License, and AGPL appear to be compatible with the GPLv3, but I don't want to make a newbie mistake when I put it on Github.

Edit: before you close this question based on the topic of "licensing", take a look at the 43,000+ other questions about licensing on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=licensing

This question asks for an unambiguous answer about programming, not for opinions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues.

Comment: Historically, licensing issues (eg. GPL) have always been considered on-topic on SO because it satisfies the three major criteria: there exists a single correct answer not based on opinion, the question is applicable to a lot of people, the question is related to programming or issues with programming or tools used in programming

Comment: "Licensing" is a suggested category, so I thought that it would be okay for a question. There are 2,949 questions with that tag at the moment.

Comment: Just a question do you need MongoDB license if you are not modifying and distributing it. Just using the binaries won't be an issue right ?

Comment: @user568109 indeed. When you build an application which uses MongoDB it can be under any license. You only have to publish your modifications to MongoDB when users access it directly.

Comment: I guess I should have asked about the Mongodb driver or Mongoose instead. I will research that.

Comment: Most MongoDB drivers are licensed under the Apache 2 license, which is fine to use.

Comment: If you are interested, I have created a site proposal on area51 for everything related to open source: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing?referrer=8PFLrZ3ydnhFtbu7jPSDPA2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Why bother going out of your way to shut down a productive discussion? Licensing was a suggested term. Here are 40,000 other related questions that you might want to close: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=licensing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIT and Apache 2.0 licenses are compatible with AGPL v3 licensed components. You'll need to pay attention to which node.js modules that you include since many licenses are not compatible with A/GPL v3.

I recommend referencing the [GNU License list page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) and [tl;dr legal](http://www.tldrlegal.com/compare?a=MIT%20License&b=GNU%20Affero%20General%20Public%20License%20v3%20%28AGPL-3.0%29) if you have any future licensing questions with A/GPL v3.

Comment: Thanks for the link to tldrlegal.com. That will help.

Comment: HOw about this one that i am working with, makes me wonder now, does it look licensed out properly? - https://github.com/wolfdogg/expressBuilder